# Dimensions of posterior and likelihood in bayes theorem

Tags: bayesian, dimensions

I'm trying to do an instrument calibration, and I'm following a source which I don't quite understand.

I can set $j$, which takes values 0-63, and measure $\vec{Q}$, which is a four element vector where each element can have values 0-255. I'm trying to find
$$ P(j|\vec{Q}) = \frac{P(\vec{Q}|j) P(j)}{\Sigma_j P(\vec{Q}|j)P(j)} $$

The source I'm following states that $P(\vec{Q}|j)$ has dimensions 256 x 64 x 4, and $P(j|\vec{Q})$ has dimensions $256^4$x64.

I'm having trouble understanding how this could be correct, and I know very little about Bayes theorem so I'm unsure if this is a question I should ask about Bayes theorem itself or if it's something about my specific problem.

Comment: Probability is a function that maps to $[0,1]$ so it doesn’t make sense to be a three-dimensional array. Can you cite the source please?

Comment: Lorentzen, K. R. (1999). Duskside relativistic electron precipitation (pg 28-30). I think what is meant by the array is that each entry corresponds to the probability for a specific (j,Q), but to me it seems like the number of possibilities for P(j|Q) should be the same as P(Q|j)